# how to set full Full Screen in SVProgressHUD in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

i'm using The library `SVProgressHUD` for my project to show a spinning circle loader:

```
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.3))
        SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.white)

        SVProgressHUD.show()
```

my question is how do i make the background to full screen ?
and how do i block the presses in the background while it is displaying ?

the library:

https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

Comment: `setDefaultMaskType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set background layer color to color you need. But don't forget, if you want to change background layer color, you also have to set default mask type as `.custom`

```
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundLayerColor(.black) // your custom color
```

---

If you want to know how to customize other properties, have a look
[here](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD#customization).

Comment: Thanx, do you happen to know also on how do i make the actual spinner bigger ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog if you have "spinner" with no text set this: `SVProgressHUD.setRingNoTextRadius(yourValue)`